# Arabic text with an emoji comes with reverse side

Tags: string, flutter, dart, arabic

I have a strange behavior in Arabic text with emoji

for example

English

```
Text('Hello ') => outputs in UI as expected 'Hello '
```

Arabic

```
Text(' الله الرحمن', textAlign: TextAlign.right ) => outputs in UI  'الله الرحمن  '

    edit
    in case the following i can get result as expected 
        Text('الله اكبر  الله الرحمن', textAlign: TextAlign.right ) => outputs in UI  'الله اكبر  الله الرحمن'

// but if emoji was at the fist or end so it comes with reverse side
```

even with removig `TextAlign.right` still the same behavior

How could i solve this ? i am totally confused

Answer (score 1):

You can use unicode in text instead of directly adding the emoji.

```
Text('\u{1F600} الله الرحمن', textAlign: TextAlign.right))
```

you can search for emoji unicode and use \u{codehere}[image: preview]

Edit

Use text Direction

```
TextField(
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
),
```

Comment: thanks .. but the text depends on the user inputs !!!

Comment: I didn't get you. are you using a textfield and showing this value in a text?

Comment: yes exactly  user typing on text field and he can choice any normal emoji that supporting by android or ios keyboard .. then the value be showing in UI ..

Comment: I just tried copying the text from stack that you posted and pasted it on a textfield and got the exact result in the text also. I think you pasted only the arabic text in place of English text while typing it should display in the order of users input

Comment: yes that because you used \u{1F600} .. but i mean how could i include it with user inputs ?

Comment: No no i created a textfield and a text below one another. Pasted the Arabic text with emoji that you posted in question and displayed in the text below. I get the same output

Comment: that's so weird ,, maybe if you writing Arabic directly instead of copy paste you will see horrible result

Comment: but i also jsut copied it then paste , it is same result !

Comment: you will see the value in textfield  as expected , but not with Text Widget

Comment: updated the preview in answer. It is updated properly in text widget also

Comment: i can't understand why there two difference result such as us . i used your code but giving me difference result . ok can you make a favor to me and try to type random Arabic instead of copying ?

Comment: I dont have arabic text in simulator. Try this. Add some arabic text. Add an emoji then some more text. How does that display. Please add it to the question

Comment: i have edited my question as what you ask me to .. ' Add some arabic text. Add an emoji then some more text. How does that display. Please add it to the question'

Comment: My guess is that when an emoji is added it moves the cursor to theright instead of left in case of arabic text. Try using 
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,

Comment: Same .. in textField looks great but in Text Widget it comes at reverse side

Comment: Did you set direction in text widget also?

Comment: Yes ..basically  i am using auto_direction package that handle it auto . it is great

Comment: Try setting the direction manually once and see if it solves this issue

Comment: i tried this too .. same :(

Comment: I think only if you have emoji at the starting of the text it will change the order. is it true?